# Can Django ORM's `.first` return `None` for a non-empty queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have a very simple model called `Achievement`. In an algorithm, I reach a point in which I have a queryset for this model - named `achievements` bellow. I got in a situation in which the method `.first()` applied to this queryset outputs `None`, even though there is an element in the queryset.

In summary,

```
achievements[0] # outputs an achievement
achievements.first() # None
achievements.count() # 1
```

How can this happen? There is no default ordering for this model.

Comment: Please make a [mre] (stressing on _reproducible_ here) and add that to your question.

Comment: At the end of the statement which generates the `achievements` queryset, I've had an `order_by` call. I've removed it and instead set the `Meta.ordering` property in `Achievement`, which has fixed this issue. Still, it doesn't sound like this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

When one calls `.first()` on a queryset, the ordering of the queryset is important as that would decide what object is first. When the queryset has an order it is used, if it doesn't have one the primary key is automatically used for ordering. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) on `first()`:

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or **None** if there
> is no matching object. If the **QuerySet** has no ordering defined,
> then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key. This
> can affect aggregation results as described in [Interaction with
> default ordering or
> order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation-ordering-interaction).

This automatic use of the primary key in the order, or let's say some other ordering that you provide will change how aggregates happen (As previously what may have been in a group will now not be in a group because of the order). Hence you observe what happens with your query.

Consider the following example (The `Bar` model is not needed but that is what I already had for testing purposes):

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()


class ForeignFoo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    int_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)



# Queries start here
b1 = Bar.objects.create(value=1)
b2 = Bar.objects.create(value=2)

ForeignFoo.objects.create(bar=b1, int_field=1) # pk 1
ForeignFoo.objects.create(bar=b2, int_field=1) # pk 2
ForeignFoo.objects.create(bar=b1, int_field=1) # pk 3

queryset = ForeignFoo.objects.values('bar').annotate(total=Sum('int_field')).filter(total__gt=1)
print(queryset.first()) # None
print(queryset[0]) # Prints an object
```

Therefore instead of using `.first` you can simply do the follows to get the proper result:

```py
result = None
sliced_queryset = queryset[:1]
if sliced_queryset:
    result = sliced_queryset[0]
print(result)
```